# Display All Dropdown Values in a Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jsp, title

I want to display the dropdown values as a tooltip. Whenever the mouse is pointed on particular dropdown option then all the values should be shown in the tooltip.

```
<td width="auto">
    <div style="width: 155px;" class="selectbox">
        <h:selectOneMenu
            onmouseover="displayToolTip(this);this.focus();"
            onfocus="SelectON(this);" onblur="SelectOFF(this);"
            value="#{BusinessInf.bOwnerShipStatusI }"
            disabled="#{BusinessInf.debtypeInd }"
            id="commOwnerShipStatusIndividual" styleClass="combobox">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Pilih--" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{BusinessInf.bOwnerShipStatusIs }" />
                <a4j:support event="onchange"
                    action="#{BusinessInf.enableICRentOwn}"
                    reRender="commDateBorrowerOwns,commDatedebtorOwns">
                </a4j:support>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </div>
</td>
```

JS :

```
function displayToolTip(val){

    val.title = val.value;  
}
```

This code is displaying only the value that is selected. But I want to display the tooltip that contains all the values that are in the dropdown.

Comment: Do you really have those tabs within the code? To add some code to the question, just paste it, then select the code and click `{}` button on editor tools.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever the mouse is pointed on particular drop down option then the value should be shown as tooltip/title.

You can do this straight from the *HTML* by setting a *title attribute* which matches the *value attribute*

```html
<select title="Please Choose An Option">
    <option value="en-GB" title="en-GB">English (United Kingdom)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But I am loading values dynamically to the dropdown. Also I am using JSF, you can see the same in my post. The tag I am using doesn't have title attribute

Answer (score 0):

I used the `title=""` attribute of `<select>` as suggested in the [answer from Paul S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28699676/2257664):

> You can do this straight from the *HTML* by setting a *title attribute* which matches the *value attribute*

The `updateTitle()` function will set the `title` of `<select>` as a concatenated string from all the values in the `<option>`s.

You can call this function after you update the `<option>`s to keep the `title=""` up-to-date with its content.

```js
function updateTitle() {
  $('select').each(function() {
    var titles = [];

    /* iterate though the <option> */
    $(this).children('option').each(function() {
      titles.push($(this).text());
    });

    /* update the title of <select> */
    $(this)
      .attr('title', titles.join(', '))
    ;
  });
}

$(function() {
  updateTitle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="A">C</option>
</select>
```